# Derivative of softmax function as a matrix

Tags: neural-networks, softmax

I have a generalised n-layer neural network. Currently, I am using it to perform digit classification (on the MNIST dataset), using a softmax + cross-entropy loss setup with simple stochastic gradient descent (for now). 
$$\text{Terminology: } y\rightarrow\text{label},\, z\rightarrow\text{pre-activation vector}, \, \hat{y}\rightarrow\text{output vector (after applying softmax)} $$

To calculate $\frac{\partial E}{\partial z}$, I need to find $\frac{\partial E}{\partial \hat{y}}\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial z}$

I am calculating the derivatives of cross-entropy loss and softmax separately. However, the derivative of the softmax function turns out to be a matrix, while the derivatives of my other activation functions, e.g. $\text{tanh}$, are vectors (in the context of stochastic gradient descent), since in those cases, $\frac{\partial \hat{y}
_i}{\partial z_j} = 0$. This mismatch of dimensions cannot be resolved in my generic implementation.

One method I have for circumventing this is to convert the derivatives of all the other activation functions from vectors to diagonal matrices using, say, `numpy.diagflat(v)`. Then, I can compute $\frac{\partial E}{\partial z}$ as a matrix multiplication between $\frac{\partial E}{\partial \hat{y}}$ and $\frac{\partial \hat{y}}{\partial z}$. Does this method seem correct? And is the original formula implied to be a matrix multiplication anyway?

**Note**: I know how to compute the derivative of the loss function with respect to $z$ *directly*, however my implementation cannot support this.

Comment: I wonder why you say $\frac{\partial \hat{y}
_i}{\partial z_j} = 0$ because you use $z_j$ while computing $\hat y_i$: $$\hat y_i = \frac{e^{z_i}}{\sum_{k} e^{z_k}}$$

Comment: No, I'm saying that $$\frac{\partial\hat{y}_i}{\partial z_j} = 0$$ for activation functions **other** than softmax. That's why softmax is a different case, and I have to compute a Jacobian matrix for it rather than a vector.